# CMake Linking Path Substitute for Microsoft Asure Cross-Compiling

Tags: azure, cmake

I am porting Microsoft Azure to OpenWrt (Atheros AR9330 rev 1@mips), 
Follow the steps from https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/SDK_cross_compile_example.md and https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/58

But I encounter a bug of the CMake script of Azure:
   The libcurl would be linked by default path, for example:

in file umqtt/samples/mqtt_client_sample/CMakeFiles/mqtt_client_sample.dir/link.txt

```
.... -lcurl /home/gaiger/openwrt-cc/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libssl.so  /home/gaiger/openwrt-cc/staging_dir/target-   \\
mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libcrypto.so -lpthread -lm -lrt -luuid -Wl,-rpath
```

It is very obvious that the libcurl and libuuid have been adopted by default system path instead of the target system library path (but the openssl path is the target's ).

This bug has been reported to Microsoft Azure team https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/119, but it has not been fixed currently.

I found that if I substitute the -lcurl and -luuid as where they exist authentically (-lcurl -> home/gaiger/openwrt-cc/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libcurl.so, as for -luuid), the compilation would be passed. But the manual substitution is a toilsome work (for there are a lot link.txt files waiting to be modified), and it needs to be done again for next time compilation.

I have tried to modify my platform file, mips_34kc.cmake, to add the line (mentioned in the last post in https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/119 )

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Lhome/gaiger/openwrt-cc/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libcurl.so" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
SET(MAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Lhome/gaiger/openwrt-cc/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libcurl.so" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Lhome/gaiger/openwrt-cc/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libcurl.so" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

But the link.txt did not changed.

And I tried to write a script to substitue -lcurl as home/gaiger/openwrt-cc/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib/libcurl.so (use sed), it mess up the file only, and I do not know how to write a script which will seek the files recursively.

Could anyone give me a clue or help ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a shell script to detour the bug.

```
# bin/bash
#Power by Gaiger Chen 撰也垓恪, to fix azure sdk error in linking stage

echo Back up file as link.txt in the same folders

find -name link.txt -exec cp {} {}.bak -f \
#find -name link.txt -exec rm {}.bak -f \;
#find . -ipath "*link.txt" -type f  -exec cp {} {}.bak \;
#find . -ipath "*link.txt" -type f  -exec rm {}.bak \;

FOUND_LINKINK_TXT=$(find -name link.txt)

OPENWRT_LIB_PATH=""

echo "$FOUND_LINKINK_TXT" | while read LINE_CONTENT
do
    if [ -z "$OPENWRT_LIB_PATH" ]; then
    OPENWRT_LIB_PATH=$(sed -rn 's/.* (.*)libssl.so .*/\1/p' "$LINE_CONTENT")
    echo "$OPENWRT_LIB_PATH"
   fi

   echo fixing file: "$LINE_CONTENT".
   sed -i "s|-lcurl|$OPENWRT_LIB_PATH/libcurl.so|g" "$LINE_CONTENT"
   sed -i "s|-luuid|$OPENWRT_LIB_PATH/libuuid.so|" "$LINE_CONTENT"
done # while read LINE_CONTENT


FILE_NUM=$(echo "$FOUND_LINKINK_TXT" | wc -l)
echo "$FILE_NUM" files have been fixed.
```

More detail could be found in my blogger: 
   http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.tw/2017/07/build-and-exploit-microsoft-azure-sdk.html